# Not able to access Azure SQL DB from MS Navision 09 r2

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, navision

```
****Microsoft Dynamics NAV Classic****

Error while connecting SQL Azure from Navision 2009 r2 using SQL server Authentication. 

The following SQL Server error or errors occurred:

40507,"42000",[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'SUSER_SNAME' cannot be invoked with parameters in this version of SQL Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the initial response on your post [on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4a1d4afe-94bd-4827-aa29-34b7056331eb/not-able-to-access-azure-sql-db-from-ms-navision-09-r2?forum=ssdsgetstarted), it seems to be an error in the parameters being provided to your Azure SQL Database instance.

You can verify that for yourself by referring to the error `40507` on the [SQL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages) which indicates `'%.*ls' cannot be invoked with parameters in this version of SQL Server.`

If you could give more context to whether this previously worked or what you're doing to configure the connection, we may be able to give a better recommendation to resolve your issues. For the moment, it appears that the ODBC driver is presenting parameters that are causing the error.

Comment: Trying to Connect Dynamic Nav 2009 r2 with SQL Azure.

Comment: While opening database in Nav with SQL server authentication.

Comment: guess its about SQL server method SUSER_SNAME(), Navision internally calling this method with some varbinary type parameter. e.g. SUSER_SNAME(0x01.........) . 

This overload of SUSER_SNAME is deprecated from azure. Please suggest some work around

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to look- I'm not sure Azure supports that version of Dynamic Nav... Is there a reason why you're not upgrading to the newest version?